# Visualizing Groups Software

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, math-software

I'd like to have something that alouds to visualize groups. I found a software called "[group explorer](http://groupexplorer.sourceforge.net/)" but it's quite dated and visually not really appealing. I'm wondering if there's some other more recent but still simple software like that one. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly are you interested to visualise? Could you please name a few examples?

Comment: Cayley graphs and cycle graphs could be enough

Comment: I am not aware of anything newer and visually appealing. Would love to see something of this kind eventually available via GAP Jupyter interface.